# How to make big file into small chunk and then use the chunk file for comparison with another file in linux or R or python

Tags: python, r, shell

I have file-1 which is a big file with 9.9 million rows and 8 column. I have another file 2 with 3.3 million rows and 9 columns. Actually, I am extracting the rows from file 1 if column 2 of file-1 is matching with column 2 of file-2.

I used the following code

`awk 'BEGIN { while ((getline<"file-1")>0) {REC[$2]=$0}} {print REC[$2]}' < file-2 > file-3`

But file 1 is with 9.9 million row this code is not giving me any output. Whereas if I split it 9.9 million rows into 100 thousand rows then I get the output. If i split it with 500 thousand rows then again no output.

This was my split command

```
split -l 100000 -d file-1 smallfile- --additional-suffix=.txt
```

Now I need help so that I can split this files into a small chunk of 100 thousand rows and run all the small chunk into above awk command that will give me output with suffix ending as _split_file_100_thousand .. so on for example output of first 100 thousand split file3_split_100_thousand
Similarly, for 9.9 million row it will be file3_split_9.9_million

My example file 1

```
A     B    C     D    E    F    G    H
chr1  1   0.5    0.6  0.7  0.7  0.9  10.0
chr1  2   0.5    0.6  0.11  0.7  0.9  10.0 
chr1  3   0.5    0.6  0.1  0.7  0.9  10.0
chr1  4   0.5    0.6  0.7  0.7  0.9  10.0
```

File2

```
A     B    C     D    E    F    G    H    I
chr1  3   0.1    0.2  0.3  0.7  0.9  10.0 19
chr1  4   0.100  0.3  0.7  0.7  0.9  10.0 19
```

File3

```
A     B    C     D    E    F    G    H
chr1  3   0.5    0.6  0.1  0.7  0.9  10.0
chr1  4   0.5    0.6  0.7  0.7  0.9  10.0
```

Comment: Since this is an international website, not everyone is familiar with the unit lahks. So perhaps  switch that to something more international.

Comment: changed 1 lakhs into 100 thousand and 99lakhs into 9.9 milllion